# Excel - How to calculate the sum of values in a table based on text from the same cells as the value?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I need to calculate the sum of values in a range of cells, which have different and/or identical data, based on text that is in the same cells as the value I need calculated.

I have created 4 sheets: data, control, test and result; with more than 5 mil cells with formulas(mostly typed because of errors) and I need to extend the range of all sheets.

Is there a simpler way(than what I've made) to achieve the results from column B?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as `needs debugging info`; please ensure the code you've created is included.  Tagging `vba` would indicate you're working with a script; this is not a code-for-you service, but is a forum to support aiding in specific issues which can be answered objectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want column B to have that number, then

```
=left(A2,1)*1
```

will work.

If the number is 2 digits then you will have to test and deal with that.

Then sum column B:

```
=sum(B:B)
```